# How to make and use list of labels in VB.NET, WinForms?

Tags: vb.net

**How can you make and use a list of labels in VB.NET, WinForms?**

I want a 4x4 grid of labels that can be used and interacted with just like an array, e.g. `Public somearray(3,3) as Integer`. I want to be able to programmatically create, change the text of, and the location of these labels, without having to use repetitive code (if possible).

Also, as a by-question, is there some programmatic way of finding out how much space a label will take up, so as to centre it within a certain area?

Comment: Of course you could. But... without more information this question is far too broad.

Comment: @DanielCook I want a 4x4 list of labels that I can use just like ones I place in the designer. What's so broad about that?

Comment: Webforms, WPF, ASP? As for repeating things though, you can do wonders with repeater type controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `TableLayOutPanel` for your grid of labels. The labels can be access directly by their name like any other control you add to your form. You can also add all the labels to an Array or List if you like and access by index.